Default routes ($connect, $disconnect) don't work in AWS's Websocket
I am currently building a simple chat app with AWS Websocket. I noticed that only custom defined routes works, where both $connect and $disconnect aren't seem to run.
Below is my AWS Lambda implementation:
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.handler = void 0;
const AWS = require("@aws-sdk/client-apigatewaymanagementapi");
const ENDPOINT = 'https://[APIId].execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/production';
const client = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({ endpoint: ENDPOINT });
const names = {};
const sendToOne = async (id, body) => {
    //send message to a connectionId
};
const sendToAll = async (ids, body) => {
    //send message to all connectionIds
};

const handler = async (event) => {
    if (event.requestContext?.connectionId && event.requestContext?.routeKey && event.body) {
        const { connectionId, routeKey } = event.requestContext;
        console.log('route key: ', routeKey)
        let body = {};
        try {
            body = JSON.parse(event.body);
            console.log('body', body);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error("Error parsing body: ", error);
        }
        switch (routeKey) {
            case '$connect':
                await sendToOne(connectionId, { message: '[System] Welcome to the chat!' });
                break;
            case '$disconnect':
                await sendToAll(Object.keys(names), { message: `[System] ${names[connectionId]} left the chat.` });
                delete names[connectionId];
                await sendToAll(Object.keys(names), { message: `[System] Members: ${getAllNames(names)}` });
                break;
            case 'setName':
                if (body.name) {
                    names[connectionId] = { name: body.name };
                    await sendToAll(Object.keys(names), { message: `[System] ${body.name} joined the chat.` });
                    await sendToAll(Object.keys(names), { message: `[System] Members: ${getAllNames(names)}` });
                }
                break;
....

Running setName work, it did produce the messages and the console.log did log the correct routeKey and body in CloudWatch. In contrast, when I initiated a connection (using the terminal with wscat -c wss://[APIid].execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/production/) or end the connection with control + C it didn't produce any messages and the console.log didn't produce any logs, there were also no errors in CloudWatch.
